# How to renew information of iframe using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, refresh

I am trying to renew information in iframe, which was generated by JS but unsuccessfully. I have a form in HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="calc.php" target="my_iframe">
<input type="submit" value="Calc" onclick="Frame()"/>
```

Here some parameters are given to php file via submit button, which calculates answer

JS creates iframe:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function Frame()
{
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute("src", "calc.php");
iframe.setAttribute("name", "my_iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("width", "500px");
iframe.setAttribute("height", "400px");
iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
iframe.setAttribute("id", "second");
document.getElementById("first").appendChild(iframe);
};
</script>
```

into div:

```
<div id="first" class="answer"></div>
```

After first press of Calc button everything is working correctly, but when I change the parameters in form and press Calc button JS renews information in first iframe and generates one more iframe with errors (that's ok, it shows errors of because it does not have input).

How could I edit JS to use only one iframe, and renew information only there everytime I press Calc button? Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

What you ar doing with `appendChild(iframe)` is to add an additional element to the page, with is not what you want.

Try replacing:

```
document.getElementById("first").appendChild(iframe);
```

with:

```
document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = iframe;
```

Also the `width` and `height` attributes are just supposed to be numbers without `px`.